# Aptana does not starting on the Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: aptana

I have installed aptana. I used this guide http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/ to do that.

My issue is that after I press the launch icon it start loading (black screen with green progress bar) after 2 seconds it dissappearing and nothing happen

Comment: Shouldn't be this more suited to http://askubuntu.com/?

Comment: just to have a quick answer - askubuntu has less visitors